Would a muon placed in a confinement smaller than most electron wavelengths decay slower?
We know that between two perfect mirrors certain photon frequencies become disallowed.
The casimir effect is often even described as a lack of virtual photons of certain frequencies within quantum fluctuatuations.
If we manage to build a small enough mirror for charged particles(large enough to allow muons, but small enough to disallow most electrons) would this mean the muon could only decay into high energy electrons and would that lower the rate of decay?

In principle, yes. (We do a version of this, called the Purcell effect, for light.) In practice, the typical wavelength of an electron is $h / (m_e c) \sim 10^{-12} , \mathrm{m}$, which is much smaller than the size of an atom, so we can't actually make a real mirror that accomplishes this.

Yeah I mainly thought about standing laser waves in the picosecond range as a tool for confinement. Though I think we have not progressed behind single pulses in that frequency range?

Particles confined enough change their decay rates, since the rate depends on the available phase space volume. Prevent the possibility of enough decay states and the rate goes down.
In the case of negative muons it looks like one can both increase and decrease the decay rate by binding between different elements (see also this calculation).

I would suggest to go to basics.
Calculate the decay rate. Exclude the contributions from those momenta of the virtual particles which are excluded from the space you're considering.
